# Like Post Button in wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, function, wordpress-rest-api

I tried to make a `Like button` for Posts so i found this tutorial with a lot of searching

tutorial : https://www.atomicsmash.co.uk/blog/create-like-post-button-in-wordpress/

but not worked to me !

my code in **functions.php**

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {

  register_rest_route( 'example/v2', '/likes/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => array('GET','POST'),
        'callback' => 'example__like',
    ) );

});
function example__like( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    // Custom field slug
    $field_name = 'postlike';
    // Get the current like number for the post
    $current_likes = get_field($field_name, $request['id']);
    // Add 1 to the existing number
    $updated_likes = $current_likes + 1;
    // Update the field with a new value on this post
    $likes = update_field($field_name, $updated_likes, $request['id']);

    return $likes;
}
```

in **ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.like__btn').on('click', function(){
        // AJAX call goes to our endpoint url
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.1.8/p-test/wp-json/example/v2/likes/7',
            type: 'post',
            success: function() {
                console.log('works!');
             },
             error: function() {
                console.log('failed!');
              }
          });
        
        // Change the like number in the HTML to add 1
        var updated_likes = parseInt($('.like__number').html()) + 1;

        $('.like__number').html(updated_likes);
        // Make the button disabled
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
</script>
```

in **HTML**

```
<button class="like__btn">
    <span class="like__number"><?php the_field('postlike'); ?></span>
</button>
```

Which part of the tutorial did I make a mistake?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please describe what is not working, or maybe you get any errors?

Comment: @rank - It does not show anything

Comment: do you use Postman or other helper tool? You can send request via it and see what happend. I see one problem,  you need add 'permission_callback' => '__return_true' to register_rest_route